# Как работать с bias в нейросети

Tags: алгоритм, матрицы, нейронные-сети

Как правильно работать с нейросетью с использованием bias если я делаю ее самостоятельно(разбираю чужой код,но без bias).
Я делал так:для каждого слоя выделяю лишнюю  связь с весом(это вес для bias).

При прямом передачи сигнала по сети на данном слое при взвешивании сигналов учитываю сигнал bias,например 1.0 и его вес про который я говорил выше.
Но когда я вычисляю  вектор ошибок для данного слоя и чтобы его же передать пред-слою,я получаю вектор не учитывающий вес к bias.Как автор говорит
"Нейрону смещения не нужна ошибка".В результате например для матрицы данного слоя (3,5) (с учетом bias) получаю вектор ошибок (4,1).Т.е. вес
bias нельзя исправить,хотя его нужно исправлять.

Похоже такой код не работает. Как нужно правильно работать с bias?

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы Вы всё правильно делаете. Используйте `pytorch`, `keras` или `tf`. Я думаю, что не стоит это писать руками. Подходите к задаче технологично. В таком случае, Вы упростите задачу и себе и другие люди не будут плеваться, когда будут читать Ваш код. Мотивации вроде "Я хочу разобраться" здесь вряд ли уместны, так как, написав тот же код на известном фреймворке, Вы убьёте 4х зайцев: разберётесь с фреймворком, посмотрите, как пишут код другие люди, скорее всего поймёте глубже проблему и не будете велосипедить.

Comment: На Keras пишу,но хочу быть крутым математиком-прогером)

Comment: @Константин Для этого Вам не нужно ручками делать скорее всего говнокод, ИМХО. Дело ваше. В конце  концов, пример с Вашей проблемой -- тому доказательство.

Comment: @Константин не по теме, но если Вы изучаете математику присмотритесь к https://betterexplained.com , а еще довольно много математики в компьютерной графике :)